# String comparison using hashcode() and length()

Tags: java, equality

In java (or any other PL that uses same hashcode function) Is it safe to say that:

> Two strings of equal length have same hashcode if and only if they are
>   equal

let's just assume the hashcode function will be

> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]

**use case:**

for comparing two massive collections of strings, it'll be theoretically faster  to use `option 1` rather than `option 2` because hashcode computation will be done once as String will cache the its value:

OPTION 1:

```
 for(String s1 : collection1){
   for(String s2 : collection2){
     if((s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode()) && (s1.length()==s2.length()){
        System.out.println("matched");
     }
   }
 }
```

OPTION 2

```
 for(String s1 : collection1){
   for(String s2 : collection2){
     if(s1.equals(s2)){
        System.out.println("matched");
     }
   }
 }
```

UPDATE:

after @tobias_k comment I realized that statment wrong, So I change the question.

> is there a max length  M for string that for any two strings of equal
>   length their hashcode will be same if and only if they are equal

Comment: Certainly not. Take strings of length 100. There are _many more_ strings of length 100 than there are different integer numbers, so there must be collisions.

Comment: Take `String s1 = "Aa"; String s2 = "BB";`. Same length, same hashcode but not equals.

Comment: typo >>> `(s1.length()=s2.length()`

Comment: A hash functions is not a [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) function, so no. And hashes are usually all the same size, so comparing the length of the hashes makes no sense.

Comment: *"So I change the question"* SO doesn't work that way. If you have a new question, then create a new question.

Comment: About your new/updated question: See Eran's answer. If there is such a max length, then it's 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Two strings of equal length have same hashcode if and only if they are equal

Certainly not. Take strings of length 100. There are *many more* strings of length 100 than there are different `int` numbers, so there must be plenty of collisions.

> is there a max length M for string that for any two strings of equal length their hashcode will be same if and only if they are equal

If there is such a length M, then it is at most 1 (and thus not very useful), as shown with the examples of hash code collisions even for strings of length 2 in [Eren's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028022/1639625) and [KDP's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028138/1639625) answers.

---

To make your comparison faster, you could first compare the hashcode, and then compare with `equals` only if the hashcode is the same.

```
for(String s1 : collection1){
    for(String s2 : collection2){
        if (s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode() && s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("matched");
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: I have not profiled whether this is *really* faster than just using `equals` in the first place.)

You could also put all the strings from `collection1` into a `Set` and then test whether the strings from `collection2` are in that set. This will basically do the same thing: First compare the hash code, and then use `equals` if it finds entries with the same hash.

```
Set<String> setFromCollection1 = new HashSet<>(collection1);
for (String s : collection2) {
    if (setFromCollection1.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println("matched");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that I've received a downvote for this answer. If there is anything wrong or unclear, please let me know, so I can fix it.

Comment: beats me why mate... answer is straight to point and well written, I would up vote u twice if I could

Answer (score 4):

No, that's wrong.

For example :

```
System.out.println ("ab " + "ab".hashCode());
System.out.println ("bC " + "bC".hashCode());
```

Outputs :

```
ab 3105
bC 3105
```

Equal hashCode doesn't mean equal Strings, even for Strings of the same length.

Comment: very useful mate thx. just would you remove the space after your strings as with that space I get output 96287  (again for both strings ://)

Comment: @nafas The hash code computation is done for the Strings without the space. The space was added just to make the output clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Two strings of equal length have same hashcode if and only if they are equal - NOT NECESSARILY.

check this   "FB" and "Ea" are of same length and has same hashcode but they are not equal.

```
    String s = new String("FB");
    String s1 = new String("Ea");
    System.out.println(s.hashCode()); //2236
    System.out.println(s1.hashCode()); //2236
    System.out.println(s.hashCode()==s1.hashCode()); //true
    System.out.println(s.equals(s1)); //false
```

Comment: To compare strings use `String#equals`, not `==`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for speed and you matching is going to happen only once then below option is best and it is used by map implementation in java also

```
if (value1.hashCode() == value2.hashCode() && value1.equals(value2)) {
            System.out.println("matched!");
        }
```

but if you want to do matching multiple times then you should look for better algo for matching because java implementation is nave
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/string-performance-exact-string.html post has nice summary of String matching algorithm performance.